# How can I withdraw the bitcoin out?

Tags: ether, bitcoin

So I downloaded the Ethereum wallet and installed it. Once I launched it, it started to download the blocks, and I chose to connect with the mainnet. As indicated in the process, I may need to deposit some ETHs into the wallet to warm it up. 
[image]

Followed the instructions, I deposited 0.01 bitcoins, and as being said: my bitcoins were sent to an address, and then it will be converted into ETH and be sent to my wallet address. However, even after all the blocks were synced, I never saw the ETHs in my wallet, the balance is still 0.

I was trying to figure out what was going on here, does anyone encounter the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder what kind of instructions you were following. Bitcoin and Ethereum have almost nothing in common - they are two completely separate technologies. There is no direct way to convert bitcoins into Ethers.

If you sent your bitcoins to an Ethereum address I'm afraid the bitcoins are lost and unrecoverable.

Also, there's no need to "warm it up" in any sense. If you need to do transactions, yes, you need some Ethers to pay for the transaction costs, but otherwise you don't need Ether in your wallet (although, of course the wallet is rather pointless if it doesn't ever contain any Ether).

Comment: Maybe he used (or tried to use) ShapeShift.

Comment: Good point, misread that part of his question a bit. @user2970676 how were the bitcoins supposed to be converted into Ethers?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen, thanks a lot for your response. I did not make it clear in my original question. Yes, I used ShapeShift. It told me: Send 0.01 bitcoin to yyy(address), ... it will be converted into  0.1224 ether and sent to: 0x.....

Comment: Check your account with an online scanner (https://etherscan.io/) to see if the Ether has arrived. If yes, then your client is not synced properly. If not, well.. difficult to say. If shapeshift gave you transaction IDs you should scan those (either bitcoin and/or Ethereum transactions)

Comment: I contacted ShapeShifty's customer service, asking for refund, and now I already got the bitcoins back. The reason the conversion process did not go through is because I probably misused the so called "precise exchange". For anyone who may be interested: https://info.shapeshift.io/blog/2016/03/11/pro-tip-difference-between-quick-and-precise-transaction